# Why query result suddenly changed after called from other medthod in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I have problem here with query result from Eloquent, I tried to query from DB and put in variable `$contractList` in my `mount()` method and the result as expected. But when I tried to retrieve specific data from `$contractList` with `$contractList->find($id)`, the result not same as in `mount()` method.

Here is query from mount():

```
public function mount(){
$contractList = Kontrak::select(['id', 'mou_id'])->with(['order:id,kontrak_id', 'order.worklist:id', 'order.worklist.khs:id,mou_id,worklist_id,khs', 'amdNilai:id,kontrak_id,tgl_surat'])->withCount('amdNilai')->get()
}
```

Here the result:
[image]

But when I tried to find specific data from `$contractList`, properties that shown not same as in mount:

```
    public function itemSelected($id)
    {
        //amd_nilai_count not showing
        $kontrak = $this->contractList->find($id);
        if ($kontrak->amd_nilai_count == 1) {
            $this->nilai_amd = $this->calculateNilai($id);
        }
    }
```

Here is the result called from itemSelected():
[image]

I have tried use get() but the result still problem, how to get same properties same as in `mount()`.By the way im use laravel & livewire.

Comment: It is the same, but in the first you are selecting which columns to show and in the second version you are fetching all the columns

Comment: yeah, but i mean why the second one show all properties even I'm already filtered it and data come from 1 source that `$contractlist`, plus `amd_nilai_count` from `withCount()` suddenly gone. did I missed something?

Comment: did `find($id)` refectch data from database instead from saved data from previous fetch? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i read your comments you seem to mix up ActiveRecords ORM with an Data Mapper ORM. `Laravel` uses active records.

`Laravel` will always fetch models on every data operation.

```
Kontrak::select('name')->find(1); // select name from kontraks where id = 1;

Kontrak::find(1); // select * from kontraks where id = 1;
```

This will always execute two `SQL` calls no matter what and the objects on the heap will not be the same. If you worked with `Doctrine` or similar, this would be different.

To combat this you would often put your logic in services or similar.

```
class KontrakService
{
    public function find(int $id) {
        return Kontrak::select(['id', 'mou_id'])->find($id);
    }
}
```

Whenever you want the same logic, use that service.

```
resolve(KontrakService::class)->find(1);
```

However, many relationship operations is hard to do with this and then it is fine to just fetch the model with all the attributes.